# Soma de dígitos de uma string só funciona quando faço uma subtração que não entendo

Tags: c++, matemática, tipagem, char

O programa recebe uma *string* de tamanho até `10^6` e deve-se somar os algarismos. Fiz o código, porém a cada *loop* é adicionado 48 à variável soma. Se eu modificar a décima linha como `soma = soma + nome[x] - 48` resolve-se o problema. Porém, gostaria de entender do porquê disso ocorrer.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
using namespace std;

int main(){
   char nome[1123456];
   long long soma = 0;
   cin >> nome;
   for(int x = 0; x < strlen(nome); x++){
       soma = soma + nome[x] - 48;
        //cout << "O valor atual da soma eh << soma << endl;
    }
    cout << soma;
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você está pegando um tipo `char` que para todos efeitos é um número inteiro, mas ele não é um algarismo. Ele pode ser usado para imprimir um texto qualquer, mas é um número. Ele apenas tem de especial que um texto de um caractere está associado a cada número e isto pode ser impresso para mostrar ao usuário assim.

Uma confusão muito comum que a maioria das pessoas fazem (conheço muito programador experiente que não entende isto) é que um número é diferente de sua representação textual. Tudo o que você vê no computador que parece um número que você conhece não é um número, é só um texto que representa esse número de uma forma que um humano entende. O número existe por si próprio. O mesmo vale para dados entrados, você entra com caracteres que são dígitos numéricos, mas não entra com o número. No máximo tem funções que faz essa conversão para você.

Quando você pega um caractere do texto digitado está pegando um texto que não deixa de ser um número, afinal tudo no computador é número. O texto é obtido através de uma coisa chamada [tabela ASCII](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII). Ela estabelece a relação entre os números que são armazenados e os caracteres que eles representam textualmente. Então assim como 65 é a letra `A`, o 48 é o caractere `0` (você pode consultar a tabela no *link* acima). Note que o caractere `0` não equivale ao número 0 quando quer o dado número do caractere. Esse número é 48. Quando você pega o texto não está pegando o número, está pegando o caractere, para converter para o número tem que subtrair 48, assim o caractere `0` vira o número 0, já que 48 - 48 dá 0. E `1` que vale 49 dá 1, já que 49 - 48 dá 1, e assim vai até o 9.

Quando fez a subtração resolveu esse problema e tornou esse algoritmo correto.

Não quer dizer que arrumou todos os problemas, por exemplo não há garantias que a pessoa não digitou um caractere que não é um dígito numérico. Também acho que deveria ter usado uma *string* de C++ e não de C, ainda mais usando `strlen()` que vai dar uma performance bem ruim neste código.

Comment: Mais uma coisa: então como eu faria pra já converter essas representações de números por números realmente? Para que eu não precise subtrair 48. E muito obrigado pela resposta :)

Comment: Nada, é assim que se faz, esta é a conversão, de forma simples e eficiente. O mais correto seria usar um iterador na *string*, não precisa usar esse `at()`. Assim fica melhor: https://ideone.com/RLay8P